# Games totaly freeze my Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, freeze, games

This is my first Linux system, so far I love it. Every singleplayer game is fine (installed through steam or heroic), and even Project Zomboid multiplayer hosted on my computer works just fine.Playing games like Warthunder, Rocket League or Apex Legends, the game always freezes, screen is stuck but audio keeps playing on loop (plane engine keeps reving, goal song in RL keeps looping, no new sounds like teammate's jumps).

I tried to Google a solution but haven't found anyone having problems solely with multiplayer games, and any other tips like deleting desklets, using a different Proton version, or reverting to an older graphics driver didn't help. Additionally, their freezes were for a few seconds or a minute, but I always got bored waiting for the game to unfreeze.

The freeze happens randomly, sometimes it freezes before even getting to the menu, other times it freezes in 5 minutes. I have not noticed any common signs leading up to the freeze.

New to Linux and to Stack Exchange so I have no idea what logs I can provide to help. I am familiar with using **REISUB** and have it fully enabled, but I don't know if I should continue with **I** if the **E** worked (Also don't know how to make it look like a key, so I made it bold).

SUMMARY: New to Linux Mint, every singleplayer game works, Project Zomboid hosted by me works fine, any multiplayer like Rocket League freezes with no clue why.

Edit: I played Warband and that runs fine, but now I tested Bannerlord and experienced the same freeze. I tried even in offline mode with network disabled, so network problems are probably out of the picture.

Comment: What you're describing could be a GPU driver error.

Comment: The REISUB thing is just a safer version of pressing the reset button; it's not something that's normal to do. I've use Linux every day for years and I *didn't* remember REISUB nor do I have Magic SysRQ enabled on my computer. Point being it's not something Linux users are expected to know.

Comment: @user253751 I thought REISUB is an alternative to Alt + F4, to close frozen and unresponsive applications. It help me a lot not having to reboot every time.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Reverting to an older driver didn't help, nor did updating back. How could a GPU driver error occur *only* in online games? (Maybe through texture streaming  on-demand, but doubt that Rocket League uses that.)

Comment: @machy https://askubuntu.com/questions/926461/whats-the-difference-between-the-magic-reisub-reset-and-holding-down-the-power - R means reset or reclaim your keyboard (this one might work in a few cases); E means ask all programs to quit (no coming back from that); S means force-quit all programs; S means flush disk caches (i.e. safely remove all hard drives though it doesn't actually remove them); U means remove all hard drives; B means force-reboot. As you can see these are emergency commands, not like Alt-F4

Comment: If your computer did not reboot or somehow stop working after sysrq+RE then I guess it *isn't* actually enabled on your computer.

Comment: @user253751 I wrote it is fully enabled, I set it to 1 because it didn't work at first. Since then I did more reading and know what each key does now. It works fine.
Edited the post with new info.

Comment: I was confused on REISUB because I read on several forums people making it sound like you are supposed to go through it all.

Comment: I'm far from certain that only "online" games cause these troubles for you. I've seen Wi-Fi/LAN card crashes and they don't bring your entire PC down. GPU driver crashes do.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yes, the post is updated with new info. The online aspect was the only connection between crashes, but since then I had singleplayer games freeze too.

Comment: Can you ping/SSH into your PC once it's crashed?